# How can I debug my data in conosle?

Tags: javascript, json, console.log

I have some react code that renders various panels in the UI.

I'm trying to debug, but when I use console statements to show `sportsTopBar.propTypes`, for example, it prints `[object Object]`. When I use `JSON.stringify` it prints empty.

So how can I debug my structures in the console?

Code snippet provided below. The code can be seen in its entirety in the fiddle.

**code snippet**

```
sportsTopBar.propTypes = {
    sports-layout: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    sportsPanelState: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    sports: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

console.log("sportsTopBar.propTypes--->" + sportsTopBar.propTypes);
console.log("sportsTopBar.propTypes--->" + JSON.stringify(sportsTopBar.propTypes));
```

**output**

```
sportsTopBar.propTypes--->[object Object]
sportsTopBar.propTypes--->{}
```

Comment: that jsfiddle is about as far away from working as one could imagine. Please supply an isolated working example

Comment: I expect `isRequired` is a function, add `()` behind...

Comment: @scniro thanks for your reply...the problem is my application is so big...its difficult to include in the fiddle...I thought code snippet will help us out `console.log("sportsTopBar.propTypes--->" + sportsTopBar.propTypes);
console.log("sportsTopBar.propTypes--->" + JSON.stringify(sportsTopBar.propTypes));`

Comment: What dialect is this supposed to be where you can define a function like `render() {...}` an object property containing a dash without surrounding it with quotes?

Comment: @dtanders can you update in my code its confusing :(

Answer (score 2):

## Problem 1

### Syntax error

`sports-layout:` should be `"sports-layout":`

## Problem 2

### You're implicitly casting to string

Your comment on this answer made me realize what all this is about. You want to see what this object looks like in the console, and can't get it to output as expected. So, this line:

```
console.log("sportsTopBar.propTypes--->" + sportsTopBar.propTypes);
```

Has the problem of using `+` to concat the leading string to the value you're wanting to see in the console. This concatentation is causing an implicit cast to string of your object, thus the output of `[object Object]` where you expected to see the actual object. `[object Object]` is the `toString` output of an object.

So to get these logged together in the same output, you need to take advantage of `console.log`'s allowance for multiple parameters:

```
console.log("sportsTopBar.propTypes--->", sportsTopBar.propTypes);
```

Notice that what I've done is replace the `+` with `,`. Each will now be logged as given, with no casting done on them.

## Problem 3

### JSON cannot represent functions

Per [JSON.org](http://www.json.org):

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> - A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
> - An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

I assume that `React.PropTypes.string.isRequired` is a function. As such, the serialized output of any object with a property that references that function will not contain a representation of that property/method. Further, your object contains *only* references to that function, so the resulting serialization (after functions are stripped) is the representation of an empty object: `{}`.

Comment: so how to see the values...if I give it in quotes its printing like this `sportsTopBar.propTypes--->{"sports-layout":"React.PropTypes.string.isRequired","sportsPanelState":"React.PropTypes.object.isRequired","sports":"React.PropTypes.object.isRequired"}
`

Comment: thanks so much...I learned so much from you...can you be my mentor

Comment: Keep asking questions here on SO--we'll all be your mentor! :)

Comment: but how to find the value inside it `React.PropTypes.string.isRequired` its just printing it not the value inside it

Comment: I don't know anything about the function you're referencing--I've never used react